Have Typescript know one of the union types in React component
Let's say I have an object of type:
type BulkItem = { id: number; type: 'bulk'; tonnage: number }
type RegularItem = { id: number; type: 'regular'; weight: number }
export type CartItem = BulkItem | RegularItem // there could be more item types here

Now, in my component, let's say I get a list of CartItems that I want to map across and display things.
const items = getCartItems(...)

<div>
    {items.map(item => {
        switch(item.type) {
            case 'regular': return (<div>Weight: {item.weight}</div>)
            case 'bulk': return (<div>Tonnage: {item.tonnage}</div>)
        }
    })}
</div>

Now, I get a TS error saying that item.weight does not apply to CartItem because bulk items don't have a weight property. Likewise, item.tonnage does not apply to CartItem because regular items don't have a tonnage property.
I know this is kind of a contrived example but I'm basically asking if there's a way to coerce each item in a list to be of a type that I would expect it to be in each case of the switch statement?

According to this plaground your example should work fine. Is your CartItem a union with another type that may match multiple subtypes? Having a subtype with {type: string} for example...

"I know this is kind of a contrived example" You may made your example too contrived and it no longer has your original problem.

It's important to note that your items list must have type CartItem[] and NOT (BulkItem | RegularItem)[], as the latter won't be recognised as a discriminated union.

@OliverTonnesen I don't think that's correct: https://tsplay.dev/WY1dvW

@AlexWayne huh you're right. I tried it out in a random typescript project I had open, so it's possible I just had a wonky config. Apologies for the misinformation in any case!

Actually, there is no typescript bug in your code, unless the getCartItems returns CartItem[].
If the typescript still gives error, you can use Type Guard Functions to identify a CartItem is a BulkItem or RegularItem.
const isRegularItem = (item: CartItem): item is RegularItem => item.type === 'regular';
const isBulkItem = (item: CartItem): item is BulkItem => item.type === 'bulk';

Then, employ type narrowing with if statements:
<div>
  {items.map(item => {
    if (isRegularItem(item)) {
      return <div key={item.id}>Weight: {item.weight}</div>;
    }
    if (isBulkItem(item)) {
      return <div key={item.id}>Tonnage: {item.tonnage}</div>;
    }
    return null;
    })}
</div>


Type guards can be great, but they should only be used when the existing typescript narrowing features cannot be used. And since there's no actual issue with the OPs posted code, then there's no reason to use a typeguard. And when written badly, they can lie to you. This (x: unknown): x is string => true will tell you anything is a string, and it would be wrong.

I agree with you @AlexWayne, but the type guards which I gave don't use functions returning just true. Anyway, I don't see any typescript bug in the main issue, typescript can narrow the union types I believe.

Nothing wrong your answer. The problem in this whole thread is related to the example provided by OP where the problem they're experiencing is no longer valid because they've contrived their example way too much.
